# how to display multiple line text by pyramid

Tags: python, render, pyramid

i'm using pyramid to display a multiline text. such as:

```
txt="""
abc
def
"""
```

html render(such as jinja2) does not have paragraph tag 
so i add paragraph tag to txt, but finally, it render with escape

```
&lt;p&gt; abc &lt;/p&gt; ...
```

so how to correctly display the multiline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ambiguous whether you have autoescaping set to true or not, but if that is the case, then when rendering, make sure you add " | safe".

ie: {{post.render | safe }}

More information on escaping can be found here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#html-escaping

Answer (score 1):

[`Working with automatic escaping`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping) in `jinja2` is easy - you eather apply `|safe` filter inside a template or your variable passed to the template should be of type [`Markup`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Markup)

Answer (score 0):

\r\n or \n does not suffice ?  if i understand your question you are simply trying to add linebreaks. Use those special character sequences per your OS